# What does 'it' refer to in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, pronouns

What does the following **it**(bold letter) refer to? Is this a Provisional subject? If you have any good idea, please let me know.

> It is estimated that about one-third of the population in Sub-Saharan
> Africa must travel at least thirty minutes to the closest water
> source, often several times a day. This burden falls mainly on women
> and girls. As a result, many women cannot do any other work, and many
> young girls cannot attend school. Children are also usually the first
> to get sick or die from drinking dirty water.     People in developed
> countries like Japan may feel that this problem does not relate to
> them, but this is not the case. Developed countries contribute to this
> problem in a major way through their use of virtual water. Virtual
> water refers to the total amount of water used to make and transport
> food and products like clothing and electronics. For example, *when
> considering the amount of water **it** takes to raise, prepare, and
> transport beef, a single hamburger uses about 2,400 liters!* Japan is
> the second largest virtual water importer in the world and, as such,
> shares responsibility for the Earth’s water crisis.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like an "empty it" or "dummy it".  See: [this description of the concept](https://editorsmanual.com/articles/grammatical-subject-in-its-raining/).  This "it" isn't referring to anything in specific, instead, it acts as a placeholder subject for the grammatical purpose of the subject when we don't need one.

One way to rephrase the sentence and keep the exact same meaning would be:

> ...when considering the amount of water required to raise, prepare, and transport beef...

Note how this rephrasing uses the passive voice, which also removes the subject.